# schedule local notification which will execute everyday but not on Sunday (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsdate, uilocalnotification

i have a scheduled local notification which is set to repeat every day :

```
    //scheduling notification
    let dateComp:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComp.year = 2015;
    dateComp.month = 01;
    dateComp.day = 20;
    dateComp.hour = 21;
    dateComp.minute = 00;
    dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    let calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    let date:NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!


    notification.category = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
    notification.alertBody = "Demo notification."
    notification.fireDate  = date
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day

    let dateNow = NSDate()
    let noticalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let hour = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: dateNow)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

any idea or hint how can i make this notification to be fire not on Sundays ???  any hint or guidance will be much appreciated and helpful for me , thanks

Comment: @MartinR hey thanks for responding man , don't we have any other options ?  don't you think its not a proper way ? like scheduling extra 5 notifications ? instead of canceling one

Comment: As mentioned in the answer to the linked-to question: *"The API for UILocalNotification is very limited in this regard"* ... A daily notification fires on *every* day.